# SQL Modify alfabetical order, including composite characters

Tags: mysql, alphabetical-sort

I want to order by a modified alphabetical order, including ‘letters’ that are made of 2 or 3 characters (i.e.:  a, ä, ch, chh, ch’, i, ï, j, k, kh, k’, l, ll, m, n, ñ, p, ph, p’, q, qh, q’, r, s, t, th, t’, u, ü, w, x, y, ¨ this is a real alphabet from *Aymara* language), using this criteria I need to make, for example, the following words ordering, small part of a dictionary

`NORMAL ORDER   DESIRED ORDER
 Yaq’a          Yaqana
 Yaq’araña      Yäqata
 Yaq’asiwi      Yaqiña
 Yaqana         Yaqulla
 Yäqata         Yaqha
 Yaqha          Yaqhipa
 Yaqhipa        Yaq’a
 Yaqiña         Yaq’araña
 Yaqulla        Yaq’asiwi`

The composite letters can be located in any place of the word.

Working in MySQL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem of Collation, that is the definition of how to order the words for a given language within a character set

If the language already have a collation definition in mysql, the instruction COLLATE will call the collation definition, and the query will be presented using it [Examples of Character Set and Collation Assignment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html)

If there is not an appropiate definition, we can add a collation definition that
fit our needs [Adding a Collation to a Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-collation.html)